# Add a newline at end of clipboard contents

Tags: clipboard, xclip

I use `xclip` to copy the contents of the clipboard and pipe them to another application. However, if the last line that was copied doesn't have an end of line character, it doesn't show in the application.

***Question***: Is there a way to *add* an end of line/newline at the end of clipboard contents before piping the value across?

The following gif shows the behavior of (1) first copying *without* going to the end of the line and (2) second copying *with* going to the end of the line, and how the result is different in the terminal. Notice the relationship between what was copied and the prompt.

[image]

The application that I'm using which makes use of `xclip` would not read anything in with the first option, and would read the line correctly with the second option.

---

A little bit more information [here](https://github.com/sebastian-c/overflow/issues/24)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command:

```
printf "$(xclip -o clipboard)\n"| xclip -selection c
```

extends the content of the clipboard into a new string, adding a newline.

Subsequently, the edited string is copied into the clipboard (again) by:

```
xclip -selection c
```

Comment: This seems to do what I'm looking for. For the actual application, I stop before the pipe and just use the output resulting from the `printf` step. Thanks!

Comment: Since you started with a Mac, don't suppose you know if this would work with `pbpaste` too...

Comment: @AnandaMahto I am afraid in my Mac days, all I was capable of is push some buttons :)

Comment: No problem. Will see what I can come up with :-)